# If condition satisfies run macro

Tags: excel, if-statement, vba

Given Cell A1 =A, Cell A2= B
I wqnt a VBA code that
If A=B Value if true Do nothing (or run a null macro)
Value if Flase : it will trigger a macro automatically
Pls help anyone

Comment: `If A <> B Then myMacro` ?

Answer (score 0):

If A1 and A2 are entered manually and not a calculation based on formulas then the following should work:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
    'declare and set your worksheet, amend as required
    If Target.Address = "$A$1" Or Target.Address = "$A$2" Then
        If ws.Range("A1") <> ws.Range("A2") Then MyMacro
    End If
End Sub

Sub MyMacro()
    MsgBox "It works!", vbInformation, "Title"
End Sub
```

If A1 and A2 are calculated based on formulas then the following should do it:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
    'declare and set your worksheet, amend as required
    If ws.Range("A1") <> ws.Range("A2") Then
        MyMacro
    End If
End Sub

Sub MyMacro()
    MsgBox "It works!", vbInformation, "Title"
End Sub
```